# Bulk power markets hour ending convention why?

Tags: generator, load

Is there an engineering explanation for the hour ending (HE) convention common to  US Independent System Operators (ISO)? For example, hover over any MISO real time market data and they will show the HE. See link below:

[MISO](https://www.misoenergy.org/markets-and-operations/real-time--market-data/real-time-displays/)

[image: Miso real time load screen grab]